# Failed to resolve: com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar-abc:3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to import a [library](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) to my project, it throws following error:

```
Error:(8, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar-abc:3.1.2 <a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':StickyListHeaders')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar-abc:3.1.2'
}
```

Here is toplevel build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

Error details:
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':UIAppTemplate'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':UIAppTemplate:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar-abc:3.1.2.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/rigupta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/manuelpeinado/fadingactionbar/fadingactionbar-abc/3.1.2/fadingactionbar-abc-3.1.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/rigupta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/manuelpeinado/fadingactionbar/fadingactionbar-abc/3.1.2/fadingactionbar-abc-3.1.2.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/rigupta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/manuelpeinado/fadingactionbar/fadingactionbar-abc/3.1.2/fadingactionbar-abc-3.1.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/rigupta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/manuelpeinado/fadingactionbar/fadingactionbar-abc/3.1.2/fadingactionbar-abc-3.1.2.jar
>        Required by:
>            android - AS:UIAppTemplate:unspecified
>   Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` you have to add

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
```

It this way gradle knows where are the dependencies to download.
It is somenthing different from the repositories inside the `buildscript` block.

Otherwise you can add in the *top-level* `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone landed here using `maven` with `url` (`jitpack`), add that inside app -> gradle inside `allprojects` `repositories`.

ex:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot dependency

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```